# Deep clone - InjectFrom - ValueInjecter - parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, clone, deep-copy, valueinjecter

I am trying to do a deep clone of `tags`using `ValueInjecter`

Here is the code.

```
  IList<Tag> processTags = new List<Tag>();
  processTags.InjectFrom(tags);
```

The second line throws `parameter count mismatch`

Why is it so and how do I overcome it?

Comment: you need to create a list do a foreach and call .InjectFrom for each tag in the first list you can also learn about it here: https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter

Comment: @Omu so it means I will not be able to deep clone a list rather I need to do for each item in a list by  looping. Correct me if I am wrong.